# Cycles Render Option Not Showing Up In Blender 2.77

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I installed Blender 2.77 RC1 but I only get the Blender Render and Game Engine options for rendering.  Cycles doesn't appear in the pull down menu.

I've reinstalled 2.77 and checked all the preferences, but no joy.

Anyone having the same problem?  If so, is there a trick of some sort to get to the Cycles opation?

Answer (score 2):

You have to enable it in user preferences and addons. [image]